# Unity Mute during pause

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

Well I've been trying to make a pause menu where the user could mute music/sfx. But so far no luck, basically in this project all my audiosources are registered to the sound manager event of sfx/music state change.

In this event they mute/unmute based on that state. It was working fine until I tried it on a pause menu. I can only guess it has something to do with the Time.scale being at 0.0f because if I mute the sound it just keeps playing until I close the pause menu and the time scale returns to 1.0f. Same happens with unmuting.

Does anyone know a way to deal with this?

Comment: I think it depend on how your pause menu was made, can you give us more details on this ?

Comment: Do you set Time.scale = 0f before or after you mute the sounds?

Comment: Do you want to pause all sounds or leave a background music at least? and add the code you are using to manage your audio sources.

Comment: some of your code will be useful

Comment: Time scale is set to 0.0f before the mute (since you mute from inside the pause menu). my sounds are divided between sfx and music so both have their own mute.

Comment: The pause menu basically just sets the time.scale to 0.0f and then pops up a window on which the user can mute/onmute.

The way that the sound is managed is with a delegate on the sound manager, all my audiosources have a script attached that registers to this and when the sound managers tells, for example, mute to all sfx they get called and they do mute themselves, I can see the mute get ticked on the editor. but the sound keeps playing until the time scale goes back to normal

Comment: Are you looking to pause the sounds, or just mute them? If it's the latter, set up an AudioMixer and have all the sounds play through an appropriate group. All you then need to do is mute that group. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioMixer.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could freeze physics and movements of your object, scripts to false during pause, instead of using timescale to 0.

Answer (score 0):

When Time.timeScale is set to zero Just call the Pause function of AudioSource which you want to stop during pause state.

`GetComponent<AudioSource>().Pause();`